# Radio button value didn't passed to post function in jquery

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I am trying to get value from radio button say if gender is male or female. I get it store in value variable but while passing it to $.post it not working? 
The code snippet is  -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.

  $("input:radio[name=gender]").click(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    alert (value);
  });
  alert (value);
  $.post("gendersearch.php", {queryString: ""+value+""}, function(data) { // Do an AJAX call
    $('#suggestions').fadeIn(); // Show the suggestions box
    $('#suggestions').html(data); // Fill the suggestions box
  });

});
```

HOw this can be corrected? What is the problem.

Comment: i dont understand when do you want the POST to happen? on page load? on radio click? because in this case the post will happen while the document is readh regardless of the radio button click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested you either do this in two ways -

**First one**

Declared `var value = '';` just above your click function, as like the code below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
   var value="";
  $("input:radio[name=gender]").click(function() {
   value = $(this).val();
    alert (value);
  });
  alert (value);
  $.post("gendersearch.php", {queryString: ""+value+""}, function(data) { // Do an AJAX call
    $('#suggestions').fadeIn(); // Show the suggestions box
    $('#suggestions').html(data); // Fill the suggestions box
  });

});
```

**Second**

Another way is to declare  the post method inside the click function

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      // Handler for .ready() called.

      $("input:radio[name=gender]").click(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        alert (value);
 $.post("gendersearch.php", {queryString: ""+value+""}, function(data) { // Do an AJAX call
        $('#suggestions').fadeIn(); // Show the suggestions box
        $('#suggestions').html(data); // Fill the suggestions box
      });
      });
      //alert (value);
    });
```

Well I think it works both ways. But the first one is more ease! and better.

Comment: yeah it works in both ways but i too feel first one is better. Though others also ave the same ans but you gave two so i accept yours

Answer (score 3):

```
$("input:radio[name=gender]").click(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        alert (value);
    });
      alert (value);
```

Please check the scope of the variable `value` Define it outside and try like this

```
var value = '';
  $("input:radio[name=gender]").click(function() {
            value = $(this).val();
            alert (value);
  });
  alert (value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the `value` variable outside the `click` event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
    var value = "";
    $("input:radio[name=gender]").click(function() {
        value = $(this).val();
        alert(value);
    });
    alert(value);
    $.post("gendersearch.php", {
        queryString: "" + value + ""
    }, function(data) { // Do an AJAX call
        $('#suggestions').fadeIn(); // Show the suggestions box
        $('#suggestions').html(data); // Fill the suggestions box
    });
});
```